# Remove top link from Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, custom-masterpage

I am trying to remove the top links "Outlook", "OneDrive", "Sites" etc. from a team site in Sharepoint online.

I have gone through all I can find online and from a former similar question, but I still have not succeeded. The closest I have come is that I am able to remove the links in console view in the browser by changing css. I have then found a class called "o365cs-nav-O365Links", and if I set style="display: none" for this, then all the links disappear in the console window. I have also found ID's for specific links, where the same works:

Outlook: ID "O365_MainLink_ShellMail" 
Calendar ID: "O365_MainLink_ShellCalendar" 
Persons ID: "O365_MainLink_ShellPeople" 
OneDrive ID: "O365_MainLink_ShellDocuments" 
Sites ID: "O365_MainLink_ShellSites"

However, the problem is that I can not find these classes or ID's anywhere in the seattle master file? So I do not know how to set these properties from the master file? I have used "find" to go through the master file looking for both the classes and ID's identified from the console view, but I can not find it in the master file.

Can anyone tell me how to actually accomplish this by editing the master file?

Answer (score 4):

These links are loaded dynamically using the delegate controls so you wont' find these link in master page. To hide these links, add the following to your css file referenced from your master page (suggested) or add it to your master page.

```
<style type="text/css">
#Suite_MainLink_ShellMail, #Suite_MainLink_ShellCalendar, #Suite_MainLink_ShellPeople, #Suite_MainLink_ShellSites, #Suite_MainLink_ShellDocuments {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: With the "resent" rename of IDs in Office 365 the `Suite_` prefix was changed to `O365_`. So it's a good practice to have both sets.

Comment: I might be stupid, but I still have not been able to succeed with this. When inserting it to the masterpage, the links are still present. I have also tried changing the prefix to O365_. <br /> Can you please let me know exactly where to place it in the master page so I know I am correct? I have tried several places within the <head> tag.